# How can I cover my kettle's spout?

Tags: kitchen

I need something sturdier than aluminium foil or plastic wrap to cover my [kettle](https://www.amazon.ca/Hamilton-Beach-40998C-Stainless-Electric-Kettle/dp/B00ZPN3O2I/ref=zg_bs_6647628011_4?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=ZJTN7T085M2PQ8CSFF49)'s exposed spout to block dust from entering, whenever it's not used. Please see beneath.

So the covering doesn't have to seal the spout, or withstand temperatures over 70°C.

[image]

Comment: Does it have to seal the spout off? Does it need to be able to withstand cooking temperatures? How about air pressure? If you describe what it's for, that will help too.

Comment: @JohnLocke Thanks. I was too dumb to foresee those questions. Is my post better? BTW, are you a fan of John Locke the philosopher?

Comment: Yes, that really helps the question. And no, if you're looking it up, add the word lost to the end of your search and you will find someone quite different. As for the kettle, how often are you using it and about how wide is the spout?

Comment: The pictured part is a strainer for particles in the kettle rather than a dust cover to keep dust out. They're the first part to fail over time and use due to heat. Replacements are available as they are the same for many different brands from Toastess™ to Taylor-Hobbs™

Comment: @JohnLocke My family and I use the kettle daily, at least 5 times. The spout's 5 cm wide and 3 cm tall.

Comment: Unless you're on a building site, covering the kettle spout is more trouble than it's worth (you're spending time for no measurable health benefit). Source: whole countries use kettles where the spout isn't covered. When you pour your tea into a mug, that will sit collecting dust for 15 minutes or so before it's at drinking temperature. Are you going to cover those too?

Answer (score 4):

The old-fashioned way of protecting objects from dust is a “dust-cover” - originally a tightly woven linen sheet that was used to cover unused furniture.

For your kettle, a tea-towel should work as a cover. If you use the kettle rather regularly and the surroundings are not super dusty (think regular household vs. building site or workshop), any kind will do, in the other cases, pick those that are more tightly woven and maybe fold them to get two or more layers.

If you are crafty and so inclined, you can always take the suggestion from above and make something that is tailored to the shape of your kettle - think slip-cover or tea-cozy - also with multiple layers if extra protection is required.

Answer (score 0):

To protect the kettle, go to the store and get some large cotton balls. Stuff one or two of them in the spout and that should be enough to stop dust from getting in. This works best if the spout is the right size and you don't use the kettle frequently. If you do, it just means you have to be careful to keep the cotton ball clean. Just make sure not to set the cotton ball on a dusty or dirty surface like a counter and put it back in, you will be introducing dirt directly into the filter. If the cotton ball gets dirty, throw it out and use another one.

Alternatively, cardboard might work. You can cut out a piece of cardboard to fit snugly in the spout. Then take some string or fishing line and tape it to the underside of the cardboard. When you put the cardboard in, make sure the string is attached to the underside and the end hangs out of the spout. The cardboard will block dirt from getting in, and to take it out, just pull the string.

Comment: Stuffing a cotton ball into the spout is likely to introduce more debris into the hot water rather than less. Cotton balls leave lint everywhere. The scale on the kettle has sharp edges that will snag the cotton.

Comment: The comment from the original poster before your answer says the kettle is used 5 times a day at least.

Comment: @Stan I know, I was waiting for that response to post my answer. I was pointing out that that solution does not work as well if the kettle is used frequently.

Comment: @Hobbes Another reason why that is not the best solution for frequent use. However, any snagged pieces can be removed by hand or by rinsing with water. Also, the question asks how to keep dust out of the kettle, not how to keep debris out of the water. I assume the OP isn't leaving water in the kettle all the time, my impression is that they have it empty most of the time or dust would not be a problem.

Comment: Cotton balls + wet spout is a bad combination, imho.

Comment: @Stephie That's a fair point. I think all of the points in these comments show that cotton balls would only be an effective solution for long-term storage.